# Quotients of the Ordered Square

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $[0,1]^2$ be the ordered square; i.e. it has the order topology given by the dictionary order.  This is a first countable compact space.  Let $\Delta=\{(x,x)\mid x\in [0,1]\}$.  Then is the quotient space $[0,1]^2/\Delta$ first countable?

It isn't hard to see that there is a countable basis at every point of $[0,1]^2/\Delta$ that isn't the equivalence class of the diagonal $\Delta$, but I can't seem to figure out whether the equivalence class $[\Delta]$ has a countable basis or not.  I feel inclined to say that it does not, as by the fact that $[0,1]^2/\Delta$ is a quotient space, if $q:[0,1]^2\rightarrow [0,1]^2/\Delta$ is the quotient map that sends each element to its equivalence class, $U\subset [0,1]^2/\Delta$ is open iff $p^{-1}(U)$ is open.  In particular, $U$ is a neighborhood of $[\Delta]$ in $[0,1]^2/\Delta$ iff $p^{-1}(U)$ is an open set containing $\Delta$.

EDIT: $\Delta$ is not closed.

If this quotient space is first-countable, do there exist quotient spaces of $[0,1]^2$ that are not first-countable?

Comment: I haven't thought in any detail about your actual question, but I do want to point out that $\Delta$ is not closed. In fact its closure contains both the upper and lower edge of the ordered square. (Think about neighborhoods of these points!) The result you are referencing to show closedness is only for the product topology.

Comment: Ah, indeed you are correct.  I'll correct that.  Thanks!

Comment: I deleted my answer because I boneheadedly assumed the quotient map is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $q:[0,1]^2\to[0,1]^2/\Delta$ be the quotient map, and let $p$ be the point in the quotient that corresponds to $\Delta$. Suppose that $U\subseteq[0,1]^2/\Delta$ is an open nbhd of $p$; then $q^{-1}[U]$ must be an open nbhd of $\Delta$ in the lexicographically ordered square. This means that there must be functions $f_U:(0,1)\to(0,1)$ and $g_U:(0,1)\to(0,1)$ such that:

- $f_U(x)<x<g_U(x)$ for each $x\in(0,1)$, and
- $\{x\}\times(f_U(x),g_U(x))\subseteq q^{-1}[U]$ for each $x\in(0,1)$.

Use these functions $g_U$ and $f_U$ to show that if $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is any countable family of open nbhds of $p$, there is an open nbhd $V$ of $p$ such that $U_n\setminus V\ne\varnothing$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$; this shows that no countable family of open nbhds of $p$ can be a base at $p$.

Comment: My original intuition was to take the supremum of all $f_{U_n}$ and the infimum of all $g_{U_n}$ to define a new $f$ and $g$ that provides a new open set.  However, this approach does not work in two ways; first, $f$ and $g$ could end up being $x$, or if all the $f_{U_n}$ are equal and all the $g_{U_n}$ are equal, then $f=f_{U_n}$ and $g=g_{U_n}$.  It seems like your hint points towards using these countably-many functions to create a new pair $(f,g)$ that in effect get `closer' to $\Delta$ than all of the functions $f_{U_n}$ and $g_{U_n}$.  Is this the right direction I should be heading?

Comment: @Hayden: Yes, it is. And you really need not use all of $f_U$ and $g_U$: you need only their values on some countably infinite subset of $(0,1)$, one point for each $U_n$. If you’re familiar with Cantor’s diagonal argument, you’ll find that this is somewhat similar.

Comment: Ah, that makes it very clear.  Another approach is to define $f$ and $g$ piece-wise such that on the interval $(1/(n+1),1/n]$ ($(1/2,1)$ for $n=1$) as $(x+f_{U_n}(x))/2)$ and $(x+g_{U_n}(x))/2)$.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Hayden: You’re very welcome!